# memory distribution on matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, matmul

I'm now working on a high-performance matrix multiplication library.
I have implemented a function `matmul(float* A, float* B, float* C, int M, int N, int K)` which can perform matrix multiplication where A is [M, K], B is [K, N] and result C is [M, N].

Actually, in practice, `float* A` is got from `Tensor.data()` where Tensor is a class, `.data()` is its member function to get location data is actually located. Also I have implemented a `transpose()` function. A simple implementation of `Tensor` is follows:

```cpp
class Tensor {
    void* data;
    std::vector<uint32_t> stride;
    std::vector<uint32_t> shape;

    void transpose(uint32_t dim0, uint32_t dim1) {
        std::swap(stride[dim0], stride[dim1]);
        std::swap(shape[dim0], shape[dim1]);
    }
}
```

So, my question is, if I have `Tensor A[M, K]`, `Tensor B[N, K]`, I want to do `matmul(A.data(), B.transpose().data())`, but `transpose()` doesn't change the `B.data()`, so this function cannot work. I want to know how to change it to compute the matrix multiplication between `A` and `B.transpose()`.

I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: If you want a high performance implementation, you DON'T TRANSPOSE the second operand. You change the index order in the matrix multiplication routine. This matrix layout is to your advantage, because traversing both matrices row-wise it is cache-friendly. Column-wise traversal is a waste of memory bandwidth.

Comment: If it's going to be high-performance, why did you drop known solutions like **Eighn** or **boost.uBlas**? Or use **SIMD** CPU libraries. You might switch to GPU and get **Cuda** as well. If this is a personal exercise, then *"high performance"* is a misleading phrase,  and suppresses proper feedback.